# Getting the First Start Date from Multiple Start Dates on a Medication

Tags: sql, date, express

I have a database with patients. With their Patient_ID as identifier and with multiple Start_Date and Stop_Date of medications and Action.

My problem is how to query that

```
WHERE action = 1 and start_date BETWEEN '01/10/2012' and '01/10/2013'

and where action = 1 is their FIRST Start_date
```

THERAPY TABLE:

```
Patient_ID
Start_Date Varchar
Stope_Date Varchar
Action  Varchar
```

code:
 1 = Start;
 2 = Stop;
 3 = Change

Like:

```
 Patient_ID | Medication_Code |Action| Start_Date   | Stop_Date
 10001      | Med008          | 2     | 01/01/2010  | 10/08/2012
            | Med012          | 1     | 02/09/2013  |
            | Med088          | 1     | 22/07/2009  |
 10002      | Med003          | 2     | 01/01/2009  | 01/03/2011
            | Med012          | 1     | 02/03/2012  |
            | Med081          | 1     | 22/07/2013   
 10011      | Med018          | 2     | 11/02/2010  | 10/08/2012
            | Med011          | 1     | 12/09/2013  |
            | Med028          | 1     | 25/03/2013
```

You will observe that patients has multiple start_dates. If I will be using something like

```
where start_date between 01/01/2012 and 01/01/2013 and action = 1
```

it will give me all `action =1 and between 01/01/2012 and 01/01/2013` even its not the very first Start_date that they have.

So in this example IF ITS A WORKING script

```
Select patient_ID, Start_Date, Action, Medication_code

from Patient

Where start_date EARLIEST 01/01/2012 and 01/01/2013 and action = 1
```

OUTPUT WANTED:

```
10002  22/07/2013  1   Med081
10011  25/03/2013  1   Med028
```

Thanks in advance... I will be on standby for questions.

Comment: Why note store your dates as dates?

Comment: I know, actually it should be. But this has been on varchar for so long, I've attempted to change it but the administrator said it would create problems since it's a big database. It is really annoying.

Comment: i've managed to run it with no error Daniel but it does not satisfy my requirements. STill giving me Action=1 which beyond the range dates between 2012-10-01 00:00:00.000 and 2013-10-01 00:00:00.000. This is really headache if newby in SQL.

Comment: are you converting the date in the subquery also?

Comment: Yes I did as well on your T2. like this. SELECT MIN(CONVERT (DATETIME, SUBSTRING (t2.start_date,7,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING (t2.start_date  ,4,2) + '-' + LEFT (t2start_date ,2) , 111 )

Comment: ...Is that your actual date format?  If you have to convert the column to get your data, it's going to be ignoring any indices you have.  While it may take a while to convert the column, it's going to save you in the long run - date/time/timestamps have some non-obvious characteristics at points.  Also, you shouldn't be using `BETWEEN` [with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (post is specifically about SQL Server, but applies wherever variable-precision types are used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should group for the result you want

```
Select patient_ID, MIN(Start_Date) earliestStartDate, MIN(Action) Action, Medication_code
from Patient
Where start_date EARLIEST 01/01/2012 and 01/01/2013 and action = 1
Group By Patient_id, Medication_code
```

This code groups patients and medicined togheter

I've made another example converting the strings in datetime values

```
DECLARE @from datetime, @to datetime
SET @from = '2012-01-01'
SET @to = '2013-12-31'
SELECT patient_ID, CONVERT(datetime, Start_Date, 103), Medication_code, Action
FROM Patient Pat
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT   patient_ID id, MIN(CONVERT(datetime, Start_Date, 103)) date
   FROM  Patient
       WHERE CONVERT(datetime, Start_Date, 103) between @from and @to
       AND action = 1
   GROUP BY patient_ID) pat2 ON pat.patient_ID = pat2.id AND 
                      CONVERT(datetime, pat.Start_Date, 103) = pat2.date
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT   patient_ID id, MIN(CONVERT(datetime, Start_Date, 103)) EarliestDate--, Medication_code--, MIN(Action) Action
   FROM  Patient
       WHERE CONVERT(datetime, Start_Date, 103) < @from
       AND action = 1
   GROUP BY patient_ID) pat3 ON 
        pat.patient_ID = pat3.id
WHERE EarliestDate IS NULL
ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, Start_Date, 103)
```

This code work fine for me converting the string dd/MM/yyyy to datetime.

Comment: Thanks Raphael, take note that my dates are on varchar which is really giving me a problem.

Comment: Jhun why you don't just convert start_date to datetime in the query? like convert(datetime, '23/10/2016', 103)

Comment: Yeah Daniel I did convert like this. CONVERT (DATETIME, SUBSTRING (start_date,7,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING (start_date ,4,2) + '-' + LEFT (start_date ,2) , 111 ) as Start

Comment: take a look at this link. http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/. I think you can do it in an more direct way

Comment: Thanks for the link Raphael. It is helpful. I managed to execute the code with no error but it gave me dates which is beyond the date ranges like 2009, 2003, 2008 etc. My date range is start_date >= '2012-10-01 00:00:00.000' and start_date <=  '2013-10-01 00:00:00.000'

Comment: Any more Idea Raphael. This is really a pain on the ass. It's giving headache. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I try to put down a table with some sample data to see if I can help you a little more

Comment: Thanks Raphael, i will also do some trial and error. many thanks.

Comment: just added an example, i'm not sure if the grouping is the one you want, but the data are right on my machine

Comment: thanks Raphael, But im having this error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int."

Comment: You mean varchar to date? it could be the format to which you try to convert. From the link i posted there are different formats (now 103) try to change that

Comment: Hi Raphael, I made it running but still showing up some dates that are outside the range. I think as long as action=1 it gives the date. It also gives more than one date per patient. it should only give one date which is the earliest/first

Comment: Yesterday I was out of office, if you still haven't found the solution, I just edited the post and changed the second query that i hope gives now the data you're looking for

Comment: Jhun, but this is not what you ask in you post right? what you're looking for is for a given date range, for each patient, get the the earliest date if this is in range but if the date is smaller than the range you want null.

Comment: Sorry if I did not made myself clear. It is actually what I wanted if you go back to my post. It would have been easier if just getting the dates within the range. Sorry about the confusion Raphael.

Comment: If the action = 1 and within range between dates and say there are 2 dates within range with action=1 it should give me the earliest between the two and if they are the same dates and within range give the two dates.

Comment: I'm a little confused :P, just tell me what output you expect from the sample data of your first post. because the output wanted isn't possible with the date range you wrote.

Comment: Really sorry about the confusion. The output I wanted from my post is : 10002  02/03/2013  1   Med012 and 10011  25/03/2013  1   Med028. Because they are within range, action=1 and the first/earliest start_date of the patient.

Comment: can you say me the date rage you are using? FROM and TO

Comment: FROM 01/10/2012 - TO 01/10/2013

Comment: Hope this query return your expected output, I edited my post again, but from the date and the range, only the med28 for patient 10011 should be shown, because med12 had date 03.02.2012

Comment: The output I wanted from my post is :10002  22/07/2013  1   Med081
and 10011 25/03/2013 1 Med028. Because they are within range, action=1 and the first/earliest start_date of the patient.

Comment: Thanks i will try this Raphael. I will update you ASAP. thanks for your patience for me.

Comment: WOW! you are an angel Raphael. Your solution is superb. It works perfectly. I can't thank you more for your patience and time for me. Thanks a million.

Comment: By the way Raphael. if there are the same date with action 1 and within range. Will it take both dates or just one? I understand you've used group. Thanks.

Comment: It will get you both medicaments with that date, if you just want one you have to do another group by at the end of the statement grouping patient and date, and using MIN or MAX in the select statment for the fields that are not in the group by

Comment: Ah ok. That's great Raphael. I learned a lot from you. Thanks once again for your patience with persons like me, learning to be like you with SQL. All the best with you and your family.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select patient_ID
    , Start_Date
    , Action
    , Medication_code
from therapy t1
WHERE action = 1
     AND Startdate>=@from
     AND Startdate<@to+1
     AND Start_Date=(
                   SELECT MIN(t2.Startdate) 
                   from therapy t2 
                   where t1.patient_ID=t2.patient_ID 
                   and t1.Medication_code=t2.Medication_code)
```

Should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply Daniel. But I have an error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2013-10-01 00:00:00.000' to data type int." since my dates are all VARCHAR i have converted them first with this code ,CONVERT (DATETIME, SUBSTRING (start_date,7,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING (start_date ,4,2) + '-' + LEFT (start_date ,2) , 111 ) as Start

Comment: the code iself should work, replace `@from` and `@to` with your converted dates.

Comment: yes that's what I did. but i have removed +1 coz it's giving me error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2013-10-01 00:00:00.000' to data type int." It does run now but still showing up dates that should not be there like start_date of 2003, etc.

Comment: and all the startdates are converted in the where clause?? Its now an issue of getting that data to match up when you compare them, but as dates...  The logic is there.

Comment: Yes that's true, It's a matter of comparing the dates with action=1 and get the earliest/first date_start.

Comment: I mean getting the dates to compare as dates, if you are getting dates outside the range then `AND Startdate>=@from
     AND Startdate<@to+1` is not working properly.  Are you only getting 1 date per Patient/Medication?

Comment: yes i do get more than one date per patient, when they have more than one action=1. If I'm going to put +1 it gives me an error of "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2013-10-01 00:00:00.000' to data type int."

Comment: I'm just thinking Daniel. If i dot get more than one Action=1 per patient. How do I compare this and get the earliest date? Sorry for the trouble. Thanks.

Comment: unless they started the same meds on the same date you should only be getting 1 date per patient/med..  You can ignore the `+1` from earlier, it is to ensure you capture records wit ha timestamp. like i said before, if you are seeing startdates outside the range then your conversion is not working exactly right.  The the `BETWEEN` keyword, I dont know if it would make a difference but it might.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Daniel. I will try everything. Thanks for your time.